# Finding out which U.S. state a tweet was generated in

Tags: python, shapefile, point-in-polygon

I have a database of records with latitude and longitude information (imagine this is a CSV file containing tweets and their geo-coordinates). I also have [shapefiles of U.S. states](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html). I want to add another column which indicates the U.S. state where a tweet was generated.

In R, this would be very simple: just use the [over function in the rgdal package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/over.pdf), which is really simple and doesn't require the use of any for loops.

However, I'm less sure about how to do this in Python. It looks easy to [check whether any point lies within any U.S. state,](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208546/check-if-a-point-falls-within-a-multipolygon-with-python) (though you won't be able to tell *which* state) and one can adapt the code to loop over each U.S. states.

However, I'm wondering if there's a simple function which wouldn't require the use of a for loop? If not, would someone be willing to demonstrate a relatively easy way to do this in Python?

Comment: what you are looking for is called "spatial join"

Comment: Check out this q/a, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc