# Get a column from database and populate the shapefile attributes?

Tags: shapefile, sqlite, python-3

[image: Required]

I would like to know how to get copy a specific columns from the database and add that column in a shapefile attribute table?
I am open to other better ideas.

Comment: According to your diagram, there is nothing to join on, which makes the task several orders of magnitude more difficult.

Comment: Yes, By creating a common column will help in joining them ?

Comment: Only if it contains data that permits the join.

Comment: I would solve your problem as follows: 1) if you have a file on your left, this means that it has a geom field and I would convert it to SRID 4326, i.e. transformed the coordinate systems into a common SC; 2) I would do the same in the database, i.e. created a geom field ... 3) link two tables along a common geom field + field id...Remember you should know the original SC ...

Comment: Thank you @Cyril I follow the suggested method and revert back.

Comment: Can you create an * .shp file based on a table from your database, taking into account the geometry field?

Comment: Yes probably convert it into a .shp and perform something like join attribute by location

Comment: Created geometry for both table and did a 'sjoin' using python geopandas and it worked. Thanks. (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208574/130884)