# Error while performing an intersection of a point and a multipolygon

Tags: python, ogr

I'm willing to build a tiny service that given a point location, it searches within a multipolygon, which polygon object it is intersecting. My current development is defined as this:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
import json
import requests
import zipfile
import io




'''
Returns the city, state of a certain geolocation in Brazil
'''

debbuging_mode = True

if debbuging_mode:
    ogr.UseExceptions()
    osr.UseExceptions()
    gdal.UseExceptions()

def main(lat=None, lon=None):
    # Variable setup
    if (lat == None) or (lon == None):
        # Using a generic city for demonstration
        with open('static/test/ponta_pora.json') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            for key in data:
                lat = data['latDec']
                lon = data['lonDec']
    ibgeCode = city_name = state = None

    # Define spatial reference (WGS84)
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

    # Create ogr point object
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(x=float(lon),y=float(lat), z=float(0.0)) # Forcing datatype is mandatory

    shp_file = 'static/datasets/ibge/2018/UF/BRUFE250GC_SIR.shp'
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    dataSource = driver.Open(shp_file,0)
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer(0) # Single layer shapefile by definition

    intersection = None
    layer.Intersection(point, intersection)

    print(intersection)
    print('Intersection: '+intersection.ExportToWkt())

    return lat, lon, ibgeCode, city_name, state
```

The shapefile is a multipolygon with its parts being all cities in Brazil, and the Json provides a valid coordinate in WGS84.

However, I am getting an error when trying to intersect:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ricardobarroslourenco/PycharmProjects/brazil_city_search/bcs/__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ricardobarroslourenco/PycharmProjects/brazil_city_search/bcs/__init__.py", line 48, in main
    layer.Intersection(point, intersection)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/brazil_city_search/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/ogr.py", line 2555, in Intersection
    return _ogr.Layer_Intersection(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: in method 'Layer_Intersection', argument 2 of type 'OGRLayerShadow *'
```

Any hint on what this error might be? Note: The final print is just for debuggig, ideally I would be parsing the intersected plygon object and returning its properties.

Comment: I think you want a point in polygon not an intersection - is https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208546/check-if-a-point-falls-within-a-multipolygon-with-python any help?

Comment: @IanTurton perhaps. On the third solution, ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/208574/60281 ) while iterating over the polygons, can you refer me on what the `shape` object is operating with? (for ex.: `point = shape(pt['geometry'])` )