# Is point on land (Natural Earth shapefile)

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, natural-earth

I am attempting to use the second option in [Check if a point falls within a multipolygon with Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208546/check-if-a-point-falls-within-a-multipolygon-with-python) to check if a given point is on land or water.  The shape file is from Natural Earth: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-land/

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import Point # Point class
from shapely.geometry import shape # shape() is a function to convert geo objects through the interface

#point = (-80,40) # an x,y tuple
point = (40,-80)
myshp = open('./natural_earth/ne_10m_coastline.shp','rb')
mydbf = open('./natural_earth/ne_10m_coastline.dbf','rb')
shp = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, dbf=mydbf) #open the shapefile
all_shapes = shp.shapes() # get all the polygons
all_records = shp.records()
for i in range(len(all_shapes)):
    boundary = all_shapes[i] # get a boundary polygon
    if Point(point).within(shape(boundary)): # see if the point is in the polygon
        print('land')
       myshp.close()
mydbf.close()
```

I used this code on the USG Tiger data set to tell what state an county a point was in.
I have tried reversing the order of the coordinates.  This code never finds the point over land. Can someone diagnose this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ne_10m_coastline.shp is a Polyline shapefile and not a Polygon shapefile

If you use a Polygon shapefile

With point = (-80,40)

```
shp = shapefile.Reader("/natural-earth-vector-master/10m_cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp")
all_shapes = shp.shapes() # get all the polygons
all_records = shp.records()
for i in range(len(all_shapes)):
    boundary = all_shapes[i] 
    if Point(point).within(shape(boundary)): #
          name = all_records[i][3]
          print(name)
United States of America
```

With point = (40,-80)

```
for i in range(len(all_shapes)):
    boundary = all_shapes[i] 
    if Point(point).within(shape(boundary)): #
         name = all_records[i][3]
         print(name)
Antarctica
```

.

Comment: Thanks!  As a follow up question, how could you tell it wasn't a polygon file?

Comment: see in [pyshp](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) `shp.shapeType`